# Why React npm start return error for webpack-dev-server 3.11.1?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, npx

I have the following error with `npm start` in my React application:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack-dev-server was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\Username\node_modules\webpack-dev-server (version: 3.11.0)
```

Usually I fixed this type of issue by running the following code: `npm install react-scripts@latest`.

But now it seems like that React is not updated yet to the latest `webpack-dev-server`

Now the question is how to fix that. By the way, I use `npx create-react-app` for my project, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the `node_modules` folder and `yarn-lock` or `package-lock.json` file.

And, then add this line in your `.env` file:

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

Now you can do `npm start` or `yarn start` after re-installing the packages. It should work.

**Explanation:**

For some reasons, you have two versions of `webpack-dev-server` installed in your project's `node_modules`. By setting `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` in `.env` file, we are telling npm to ignore such version issues.

Answer (score 4):

I have write following commands in react project
Open project in command prompt

1. npm uninstall -g webpack-dev-server
2. remove web-dev-server folder from node_modules(C:/Users/UserName/Node_Modules)
3. npm i -g webpack-dev-server@3.11.1
4. remove package-lock.json and write npm install

after it your react project may be start by npm start

Answer (score 0):

Check if node_modules and package-lock.json are present in your home folder, instead of your project folder. If yes, delete those two folders and then go for `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
npm yarn

If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.